# Evaluating an Integral by converting into polar coordinates.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

> **Question.** Evaluate the integral by converting into polar coordinate: $$I=\int_{0}^{\sqrt 3}\int_{0}^{\sqrt {4-y^2}}\frac{dx~dy}{4+x^2+y^2}$$

**My Solution.** Let $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{4+x^2+y^2}$. Now the region of the integration is $S_1 \cup S_2$ as depicted in the following figure:

[[image: Regiion of the integration in <span class=]$xy$-plane" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxDyS.png)

Now $I=\iint_{S_1} f(x,y)~dxdy +\iint_{S_2} f(x,y)~dxdy=I_1+I_2.$
Hence if I change the coordinate into polar co ordinate by $x=r \cos \theta;~y=r\sin \theta$ where $0<r; 0\le\theta<2 \pi$, $I_1=\int_{r=0}^{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/3}f ~rdrd\theta$

And $I_2=\int_{0}^{\sqrt 3}\int_{0}^{y}f(x,y)~dxdy$.
But I cannot figure out range of $r$ and $\theta$ when $(x,y)$ varies in $S_2$.

How can I find the range of $r$ and $\theta$ in the later case? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: In $S_2$ the angle $\theta_2$ takes all the values $\in[\pi/3,\pi/2]$. On the line segment $AB$ you have $y=\sqrt3=r\sin\theta$, so....

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen...that means in $S_2$, $r$ varies from $0$ to $\sqrt 3/ \sin \theta$...right?

Comment: Correct. ${}{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT.** The region $S_2$ is a right triangle. Your start angle $\theta$ clearly is the angle formed by the line $y=\sqrt{3}x$ and the $x$-axis. There is a right triangle there in your picture, I leave it to you to find that start angle. [Think, $\tan \theta$ for that right trangle.] The end angle $\theta$ is clearly vertical at $\frac{\pi}{2}$. This only leaves $r$ to take care of. This is the tricky part.

My hint for $r$ is as follows: clearly the radius depends on the angle, since different angles will force you to go different distances $r$ from the origin to 'land' on the horizontal leg formed by the region you labeled $S_2$. Draw a radius somewhere in the middle of your upper/lower $\theta$. Notice you have a right triangle inside of $S_2$: the hypotenuse being the drawn radius, and one of the legs formed by the vertical length along the $y$-axis of length $\sqrt{3}$. You can find the angle, which we shall call $\theta'$ between these two lines (since you know $\theta$). Does basic Trig give you a formula for $r$ in terms of $\theta'$? Can you replace $\theta'$ in terms of $\theta$? Then you're done!

You can always check your answer at the end: at the start angle the radius is clearly $2$ since it lies on the circle and at angle $\frac{\pi}{2}$ the radius is clearly $1$ (the leg of the right triangle formed by the region you labeled $S_2$. Does your formula for $r$ in terms of $\theta$ agree when you plug in these $\theta$?

Comment: ....$\theta '$ should be $\pi/2- \theta$...is'n it.?

Comment: Exactly right! It's the 'rest' of the angle from $\theta$ to the vertical in Quadrant $1$.

Comment: And so...$r \cos \theta'=\sqrt 3$ i.e. $r=\sqrt 3/ \sin \theta$...right..?

Comment: Indeed! You have $r \cos \theta' = \sqrt{3}$ so that $r=\sqrt{3}/\cos \theta'= \sqrt{3}/\cos(\pi/2-\theta)= \sqrt{3}/\sin \theta = \sqrt{3}\csc \theta$.

Comment: In general, this is always the 'trick'. 'Most' of the time, $r$ will vary between two constants (never depending on $\theta$), and all is beautiful in the world. But when $r$ changes distance depending on $\theta$, the problem is a bit uglier. But once you draw a picture, somewhere there is a right triangle to help you find the relationship between the two. It's a matter of finding the appropriate triangle.

Comment: Thank you so much.....

Comment: But now how can I evaluate $I_2$...as my calculation shows...$I_2=-\pi /12 \log 4 +  \int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2} \log (4+3 cosec ^2\theta) d \theta$.

Comment: Numerically of course! [To be clear, I mean this sarcasm on behalf of the problem, not your effort. The first integral, as I'm sure you found, evaluates nicely, while the second does not. In fact, there is not much to be done with it unless you plan on running to polylogs. The second integral itself really calls for it to be computed numerically. Of course, this defeats the purpose of the whole problem, the author probably wanted a different integrand.]

Comment: I think also soo...Thanks for your patience...

Answer (score 0):

In $S_2$ clearly $\dfrac{\pi}{3}\leq\theta\leq\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ ans also $y\leq\sqrt{3}$ therefore $r\leq\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{\sin\theta}$.